# Problems with FindBugs exclude filter

Tags: java, findbugs

I am in the process of evaluating FindBugs and am trying to make use of the excludeFilter so that the tool does not process the test packages or the generated ejb stubs.

I have tried the following:

```
<FindBugsFilter>
<!-- Match any test packages -->
<Match>
    <Package name="~.*\.test"/>
</Match>
<Match>
    <Or>
        <Class name="~.*\.^_*"/>
        <Class name="~.*EJS*"/>
    </Or>
    <Bug pattern="MALICIOUS_CODE"/>
</Match>
```

The generated EJB's are still being looked at.  Can someone provide some better direction on this.

I want to exclude out all classes that start with "_"

Example:

com/mycompany/business/admin/ejb/_AdminRemoteHome_Stub.java

com/mycompany/business/admin/ejb/_EJSRemoteStatelessAdminHome_054d51b9_Tie.java

**Updated filter file.**

I change the filter file to the following structure using the suggested regx changes and now  things are working as expected:

```
<FindBugsFilter>
<!-- Match any test packages -->
<Match>
    <Package name="~.*\.test"/>
</Match>
<Match>
    <Class name="~.*\._.*"/>
</Match>
<Match>
    <Class name="~.*?EJS.*"/>       
</Match>
```

Looks like I need to go back and brush up on my regx.

Comment: Are EJS classes still showing up? Do you have only the problem for '_' classes now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regarding [FindBugFilter](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html),

(just to be sure) are you sure you are considering the compiled class files directories, and not the sourcePath? (as mentioned in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756523/findbugs-filter-file-for-ignoring-junits)).

From the [Java element name matching](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html#d0e2197) section:

> If the name attribute of Class, Method or Field starts with the ~ character the rest of attribute content is interpreted as a **Java regular expression** that is matched against the names of the Java element in question.

Would the following regex be more accurate?

```
    <Class name="~.*\._.*"/>
    <Class name="~.*?EJS.*"/>
```

- "`.*\._.*`" instead of "`.*\.^_*`" because the [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) is supposed to match at the start of the string the regex pattern is applied to.
- "`.*?EJS.*`" instead of "`.*EJS*`" because the `?` [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) makes the matching lazy, avoiding to 'eat' EJS. (Plus "`S*`" means "0 or n S", which does not help here)

Comment: I just used your suggestion but the classes are still showing up in the report.

Comment: Here is what the report is generating:


com/mycompany/business/admin/ejb/_AdminRemoteHome_Stub.java
2
Line 33 MALICIOUS_CODE May expose internal representation by returning reference to mutable object

Comment: I have the same problem, it doesnt even exclude:


 <Match>
   <Package name="~.*"/ >
   <Package name=".*"/ >
 </Match>

Answer (score 1):

My findbugs exclude file was not working as above.  I'm using the findbugs-maven-plugin v3.0.0.  To resolve the issue I ran a build which generated findbugsXml.xml, then issued:

```
mvn findbugs:gui
```

This starts the User Interface to findbugs.  I then loaded the findbugsXml.xml file, navigated to the warnings I desired excluded, excluded them and then saved the exclusions to findbugs_exclude.xml.  I added this to the maven plugin as

```
<excludeFilterFile>findbugs_exclude.xml</excludeFilterFile>
```

The generated file works and the exclusions are truly omitted from the findbugs report.

Another great tip I found for the maven plugin was to add:

```
<omitVisitors>UnreadFields</omitVisitors>
```

Comment: This actually doesn't work at all. I desire to have *all* current warnings excluded, so I selected the root of the warnings, saved the exclusions to `findbugs_exclude.xml`, and all I got an empty file, only containing `<FindBugsFilter></FindBugsFilter>`.

Comment: the `<excludeFilterFile>` element means "Don't use this filter file". You need to wrap it in the `<includeFilterFile>` element.

Answer (score 1):

It is helpful to mention that if a class is supposed to be excluded, be careful with its **inner classes**. It took me hours to find out that instead of

```
<Match>
    <Class name="com.some.Proto" /> <!--or com.some.Proto$.*-->
</Match>
```

I should use the following config with its inner classes listed one by one

```
<Match>
    <Or>
    <Class name="com.some.Proto$Event" />
    <Class name="com.some.Proto$Msg" />
    <Class name="com.some.Proto$Query" />
    </Or>
</Match>
```

And so far I haven't found out how to exclude a class and all its subclass (not a clue in [filter](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html)), a simple regex like `com.some.Proto$.*` just does not work. And I also noticed that `$` in regex means the end of line, while findbugs read it as a text character I think, otherwise it should have been `com.some.Proto\$Query`. Besides, a valuable [regex tester](https://regexr.com/) helped me on regex by explaining every character in it.