# How to run findbug on the test code

Tags: automated-tests, maven-3, findbugs

I have a test only maven project. The folder structure is as follows

```
project-root
|_ src
|  |_ main
|  |  |_ java
|  |  |_ resources
|  |_ test
|     |_ java
|     |_ resources
|_ .classpath
|_ .project
```

When I run the findbug plugin It do not pick the classes under test.

Is there a way we can instrument the test code which is under test, to find bug?

My maven  pon has the below plugin under the reporting section

```
<reporting>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.1</version>
   <configuration>
    <threshold>low</threshold>
    <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
   </configuration>
  </plugin>
 </plugins>
</reporting>
```

when I do mvn clean compile site it will generate a report containing only classes in main module.

Need help .....

Comment: Check the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756523/findbugs-filter-file-for-ignoring-junit-tests ... it could give you hints for your problem. I'tm trying as well to applu findbugs maven plugin to src and test classes folders but no success yet.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33234692/maven-findbugs-plugin-how-to-run-findbug-the-test-classes