# Maven Findbugs plugin - How to run findbug on the test classes

Tags: java, maven, findbugs

Maven version: 3.3.3. Findbugs plugin version: 3.0.1

1. I'm using the `findbugs-maven-plugin` and I need to run findbugs
   plugin on src and test classes. Currently, it is only applied to the source classes

   ```
   Target
   |_ classes
   |_ test-classes
   |_ findbugs (only have results regarding classes folder)
   ```
2. I need to do the same for the PMD plugin. Same hint maybe?

Related issues:

- [FindBugs filter file for ignoring JUnit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756523/findbugs-filter-file-for-ignoring-junit-tests)
- [How to run findbug on the test code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31015058/how-to-run-findbug-on-the-test-code)

Findbugs maven configuration:

```xml
<profile>
    <id>findbugs</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${findbugs.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <effort>Max</effort>
                    <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                    <threshold>Low</threshold>
                    <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
                    <includeTests>true</includeTests>
                    <excludeFilterFile>findbugs-exclude.xml</excludeFilterFile>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>analyze-compile</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                            <goal>findbugs</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the configuration of the `findbugs-maven-plugin`, you need to explicitely set the [`includeTests`](http://gleclaire.github.io/findbugs-maven-plugin/findbugs-mojo.html#includeTests) element to `true` for FindBugs to analyze the test classes:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <!-- rest of configuration -->
    <includeTests>true</includeTests>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Also, the plugin should be bound to the `verify` phase so that FindBugs is executed after compilation of source and test classes.

For the `maven-pmd-plugin`, it is actually the same: the element [`includeTests`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/pmd-mojo.html#includeTests) must be set to `true` in the plugin configuration.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but instead of having 0 bugs (in src) we now have 135 bugs (in tests).